# oam_admin service unable to start

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, single-sign-on

I need help in resolving some errors, I have installed weblogic server, soa, oim, and oam to integrate my web application with OAM for SAML2.0 SSO login. When I go to url 127.0.0.1:7001/oamconsole it gives 404. When try to start oam_admin service from controls tab I got following errors in log file.

1- "This member will not join the cluster because the senior member's IP address is not an authorized host. Rejected by Member"

2- "Error while starting cluster: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start Service "Cluster" (ServiceState=SERVICE_STOPPED, STATE_ANNOUNCE)
"

3- "Failed to communicate with any of configured Access Server, ensure that it is up and running."
4- "OAM Server can not be accessed, fallback to container policy: fetchConfig failed, will keep trying ..."

I searched on google and found that there should be following block in tangosol-coherence-override.xml file.

```
<authorized-hosts>
<host-address id="1">192.168.56.101</host-address>
<host-address id="2">192.168.56.1</host-address>
</authorized-hosts>
```

I didn't find this file in my vm except in /u01/apps/fmw/coherence_3.7/examples/ folder.
Can any one kindly guide me please for its solution. 
Thanks

**Adding more while trying to start oam_admin server(weblogic administrator console -> Environments -> servers-> AdminServer->oam_admin(11.1.2.0.0) controls tab):**
vent:Id 1 name SchedulerCreate operation:ANY class:oracle.iam.scheduler.impl.quartz.CustomActionHandler sync:true status:COMPLETED stage:ACTION order:-2147483648 transactional:false event: handlerClass:oracle.iam.scheduler.impl.quartz.CustomActionHandler handler:oracle.iam.scheduler.impl.quartz.CustomActionHandler@11cfde01 result:{"string":"Done"} execTime :8.837531ms invokeWithResult:null>

<0000LKAoqh3Fw000jzwkno1NJcie000003> <1464855332757>

Flow for Process Id 21040 name c1c2101e-5511-4b49-90c7-0409e974fd70
Status : ACTIVE
Id 1 name SchedulerCreate : COMPLETED
Status : COMPLETED

<> <11d1def534ea1be0:669d25cd:1550abf149b:-8000-00000000000016df> <1464855528733>  <2016-06-02 13:18:48.733/91416.625 **Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.13  (thread=Cluster, member=n/a): This member is not authorized to join the cluster. Rejected by Member(Id=1, Timestamp=2016-06-02 10:04:36.98, Address=127.0.0.1:9095, MachineId=60314, Location=site:,machine:localhost,process:10116, Role=WeblogicServer).**>

       <> <11d1def534ea1be0:669d25cd:1550abf149b:-8000-00000000000016df> <1464855528764>  <2016-06-02 13:18:48.763/91416.655 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.13  (thread=[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', member=n/a): **Error while starting cluster: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start Service "Cluster" (ServiceState=SERVICE_STOPPED, STATE_JOINING)**

     <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'>  <> <11d1def534ea1be0:669d25cd:1550abf149b:-8000-00000000000016df> <1464855528769>  

     <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'>  <> <11d1def534ea1be0:669d25cd:1550abf149b:-8000-00000000000016df> <1464855528770>  **

oracle.security.am.admin.config.exceptions.ObjectCreationException: Cannot get implementation for type Locks.**
        at oracle.security.am.admin.config.util.GenericFactory.readObject(GenericFactory.java:243)
       .......................................................................................
...........................................................................................
.........................................................................................
        at oracle.security.am.install.startup.OamInstallTopologyReadListener.oamTopologyReadOperations(OamInstallTopologyReadListener.java:114)
        at oracle.security.am.install.startup.OamInstallTopologyReadListener.onServerStartup(OamInstallTopologyReadListener.java:89)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused By: java.lang.RuntimeException: **Failed to start Service "Cluster" (ServiceState=SERVICE_STOPPED, STATE_JOINING)** at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.Service.start(Service.CDB:38)

#      <1464855541805>  <2016-06-02 13:19:01.804/91429.696 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.13  (thread=Cluster, member=n/a): **This member is not authorized to join the cluster. Rejected by Member(Id=1, Timestamp=2016-06-02 10:04:36.98, Address=127.0.0.1:9095, MachineId=60314, Location=site:,machine:localhost,process:10116, Role=WeblogicServer)**.>

      <11d1def534ea1be0:669d25cd:1550abf149b:-8000-00000000000016df> <1464855541807>  <2016-06-02 13:19:01.806/91429.698 Oracle Coherence GE 3.7.1.13  (thread=[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)', member=n/a): Error while starting cluster: java.lang.RuntimeException: **Failed to start Service "Cluster" (ServiceState=SERVICE_STOPPED, STATE_JOINING)**

     <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <11d1def534ea1be0:669d25cd:1550abf149b:-8000-00000000000016df> <1464855541807>

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused By: oracle.security.am.admin.config.exceptions.ObjectCreationException: Cannot get implementation for type ConfigNotificationListeners.at oracle.security.am.admin.config.util.GenericFactory.readObject(GenericFactory.java:243)

[image: oam_admin unables to start]